# multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user

Tags: windows, web-services, networking, connection

i'm building new web API services hosted on windows server 2016, sometimes i faced a problem "multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again"

is there any effect to using the same user to test the services through different application "Postman, Browse, IOS Application and React application".

I used [net stop workstation /y] [net start workstation] to solve temporary this issue but it still appear from time to time.

is there permanent solution to the issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you are using username and password to that particular server to login?

Answer (score 1):

try to user this way by clearing or refreshing your server:

```
net use \\yourserveripaddresshere\servername /delete
```

I user this before and run in .bat file.

Hope it helps.